# Why the program can get right input but print wrong answer according to arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

As Above.

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char str[10000],s,s1[1000],s2[1000],s3;
char *dict[1000];
int main()
{   

    memset(dict,0,sizeof(dict));
    for(;;)    
    {
        scanf("%s",s1);
        if (s1[0] == '*')
        {
            break;
        }
        scanf("%s",s2);

        dict[s1[0]] = (char*)s2;
    }
    printf("%s\n",dict['A']);
    return 0;
}
```

I type:
A .-
B --
if right,it should print .-,and it can get s1[0] = 'A' and s2 = ".-" rightly,but I get -- as result.

Comment: Use your debugger to show where all the pointers in `dict` end up pointing to, and then ask yourself how you expect to find different words at the same exact pointer, every time. Now is an excellent opportunity for you to learn how to use a debugger; using a debugger makes figuring out these kinds of mysteries very easy.

Comment: This looks more like C, not C++. Are you using C++?

Answer (score 2):

You store all of the input strings in `s2`. The following iterations overwrite the input from the previous iteration. All pointers of `dict` point to `s2`.

Either the `dict` should be an array of arrays of char so that it can store the strings themselves, or `s2` should be so that the inputs can be stored separately.

---

Minor notes:

```
(char*)s2
```

Avoid C style casts. They often hide bugs that the compiler would see. In this case, the cast is completely redundant and can be removed.

```
memset(dict,0,sizeof(dict));
```

This is redundant, since objects with static storage are zero initialised at the start of the program.

Answer (score 0):

This coding would have been more easier in c++ (your's is C). Here's a way to do that in C way. You can also implement a search in the dictionary:

```
char s1[10], s2[10];   // max word length 10 
char dict[1000][2][10]; // 1000 (dict entries)   2 (word + meaning)  10(max word length)

int main()
{

    int idx = 0;

    for (;;)
    {
        scanf("%s", s1); // word
        if (s1[0] == '*')
        {
            break;
        }
        scanf("%s", s2); // describing word

        strcpy(dict[idx][0], s1);
        strcpy(dict[idx][1], s2);

        idx++;
    }

    printf("%s %s\n", dict[0][0], dict[0][1]); // printing dict first entries

    return 0;
}
```